# C# WCF ChannelFactory BadRequest 400 Error

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, webchannelfactory

I have created a simple webservice server, but to call methods from service class in same project i've created a webchannelfactory proxy. Everything it's working fine until i move the project(or exe version) to another machine. I can't figure it out what's going on!

I'm getting this error Message:

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.
```

with Stacktrace:

```
Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResp
onse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factor
y, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpCha
nnelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeS
pan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message messag
e, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean on
eway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan tim
eout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCall
Message methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage req
Msg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgDa
ta, Int32 type)
   at Client.IClientService.dosomething()
   at Host.ClientHost.Start(Uri hostUri, Int32 interval) in C:\(...)
```

Code:

```
WebChannelFactory<Client.IClientService> factory = new WebChannelFactory<Client.IClientService>(hostUri);

Client.IClientService proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

proxy.dosomething();  // Error shout here on Machine2
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT1:
For this example, there's no client-side(i've named Client to this Server). As i said, the code it's working with no errors in another machine(both using localhost).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
      <appSettings>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
        </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Client.ClientService" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Client.IClientService"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"></serviceMetadata>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

EDIT2:

On Browser, i got this:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'The type initializer for 'Client.ClientService' threw an
>   exception.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack
>   trace is:
>
> at Client.ClientService..ctor() at CreateClient.ClientService() at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceProvider.GetInstance(InstanceContext
>   instanceContext, Message message) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.GetInstance(InstanceContext
>   instanceContext, Message request) at
>   System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance(Message
>   message) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.EnsureServiceInstance(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

The service make use of a database, so when i copy the project to a new machine i forgot to create a new database.